# Impersonate Client Identity in WCF w/ netTcpBinding

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

Is it possible to impersonate a client's identity when invoking a netTcp endpoint operation via **configuration**? There is a section within the WCF config client as shown below:

```
<client>
    <endpoint 
        address="net.tcp://localhost:8081/tcpExample" 
        binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="myTcpBinding" 
        contract="TestTcp.IHelloTcp"
        name="NetTcpBinding_IHelloTcp">
        <identity>
            <userPrincipalName value="leethax@mydomain.inc" />
        </identity>
    </endpoint>
</client>
```

My client doesn't fail, it seems like the identity attached to the client is the current logged in user, i.e. me.

Comment: Are you calling a different server from the one hosting your wcf service?  If so, you might be experiencing the joys of delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HMm... not sure I follow. The default behavior for netTcpBinding is to use Windows credentials - e.g. your current Windows account is used for the service credentials.

That's the default right out of the box.

If you want to impersonate some **other** user, no, you cannot do this in configuration - you have to do this in code. That's the only way to go, sorry.

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = domain;
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = username;
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = password;
```

The only way to specify a different user in config would be to use a certificate which defines another user account to be used. You cannot configure a straight Windows user account along with its password in your config files.

Answer (score 3):

You really have three options:

1. Manual impersonation
   (WindowsIdentity.Impersonate)
2. Declarative impersonation
   (OperationBehavior(Impersonation = Impersonation.Required))
3. Full impersonation
   (ServiceAuthorizationBehavior.ImpersonateCallerForAllOperations)

Also, be sure that the account under which you are running your service (i.e. leethax@mydomain.inc) is granted the proper permissions at both a machine and domain level.